# How to automatically determine the minimum number of filling dots with the following constraint?

Tags: math-mode

I want to display a fraction

[image]

but with an overbrace saying `number 7 appears n times` and an underbrace saying `number 8 appears n times`.

I want the minimum number of dots to be automatically determined such that

- the most right character of the upper label, 7, 5, and the right end of the horizontal line are all aligned with the same vertical line.
- the most left character of the lower label, 8, 1, and the left end of the horizontal line are all aligned with the same vertical line.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\frac{1\overbrace{7\dots 7}^{\text{number 7 appears $n$ times}}}{\underbrace{8\dots 8}_{\text{number 8 appears  $n$ times}}5}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to automatically determine the minimum number of filling dots with the constraint given above?

## Edit

By a trial and error, I got the following but I want a smarter way.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\frac{1\overbrace{7..........................7}^{\text{number 7 appears $n$ times}}}{\underbrace{8..........................8}_{\text{number 8 appears  $n$ times}}5}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Believe or not this fraction is equal to 1/5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the constraints but perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\zz#1#2#3#4{%
\setbox0\hbox{$\scriptstyle#4$}%
#1{\hbox to \wd0{$#2$}}#3{#4}%
}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\frac
{1\zz\overbrace{7\dotfill7}^{\text{number 7 appears $n$ times}}}
{\zz\underbrace{8\dotfill 8}_{\text{number 8 appears  $n$ times}}5}
$
\end{document}
```

or as requested by jfbu with aligned dots (needs luatex)

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\zz#1#2#3#4{%
\setbox0\hbox{$\scriptstyle#4$}%
#1{\hbox to \wd0{$\let\cleaders\gleaders#2$}}#3{#4}%
}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\frac
{1\zz\overbrace{7\dotfill7}^{\text{number 7 appears $n$ times}}}
{\zz\underbrace{8\dotfill 8}_{\text{number 8 appears  $n$ times}}5}
$
\end{document}
```

not sure it looks better

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it be cooler with aligned dots for 8's and 7's ? (egreg did the math and he gets the dots almost aligned... isn't that challenging?)

Comment: @jfbu it's easy to align in luatex:-) see update

Comment: you are the boss :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some options to play with:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \frac
    {1\overbrace{\makebox[5em]{7\dotfill 7}}^{\clap{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{c} number 7 appears \\ $n$ times \end{tabular}}}}
    {\underbrace{\makebox[5em]{8\dotfill 8}}_{\clap{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{c} number 8 appears \\ $n$ times \end{tabular}}}5}
\]

\[
  \frac
    {1\overbrace{\makebox[5em]{7\dotfill 7}}^{\mathclap{\text{number 7 appears $n$ times}}}}
    {\underbrace{\makebox[5em]{8\dotfill 8}}_{\mathclap{\text{number 8 appears $n$ times}}}5}
\]

\[
  \frac
    {1\makebox[5em]{7\dotfill 7}\mathllap{\overbrace{\rule{5em}{0pt}\vphantom{7}}^{\mathclap{\text{number 7 appears $n$ times}}}}}
    {\mathrlap{\underbrace{\rule{5em}{0pt}\vphantom{8}}_{\mathclap{\text{number 8 appears $n$ times}}}}\makebox[5em]{8\dotfill 8}5}
\]

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the width `5em` I've chosen to space out the content more. The difference between options 2 and 3 is in the spacing beside the non-braced numbers.

Answer (score 4):

I believe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\ntimeslen}
\newcommand{\ntimes}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\ntimeslen}{$\scriptstyle\text{number $#2$ appears $n$ times}$}%
  #1{\makebox[\ntimeslen][s]{$#2\dotfill#2$}}%
  \ifx#1\overbrace^\else_\fi
  {\text{number $#2$ appears $n$ times}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1\!\ntimes{\overbrace}{7}}{\ntimes{\underbrace}{8}\!5}=
\frac{10^n+7\dfrac{10^n-1}{9\mathstrut}}{80\dfrac{10^n-1\mathstrut}{9}+5}=
\frac{16\cdot 10^n-7}{80\cdot 10^n-35}=\frac{1}{5}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @jfbu Nice exercise… ;-)